# Getting Channel Data in ExpressionEngine

Tags: php, expressionengine

Currently working on an ExpressionEngine 2 site that uses a channel to keep track of store locations. I didn't set it up that way, inherited this from someone else.

I'm working on creating a store location plugin for EE2 but am having issues figure out the way to get the channel entries in the plugin.

Some more details, I'm creating a third party plugin that has it's own view and js within the directory.

How can I get the locations' channel data within my main php class?

Thanks.

Comment: Plugins generally (always?) run inside a {exp:channel:entries} tag pair.  You don't really "get the channel entries in the plugin" you pass the values to the plugin from inside the entries loop.

Comment: How do you pass it to the plugin then?

Comment: Here's the plugin developer guide for EE2: https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/development/plugins.html